# facebook opengraph login

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a question about facebook login on my website. What I have now is simple login process which logs in user but each time facebook asks user to grant my app an access permission.

It looks like this:
1) user clicks "login with facebook" and is sent to facebook. He/she gives permission to access his/her account
2) I receive back an authentication token for this user

I'd like to have the following flow:
1) when user clicks "login with facebook" then he would be redirected to facebook website and after he logs in I should receive a facebook user ID,
2) search for user id in local database and if it is found then just use stored token 
2a) If user is not found then send him back to facebook to grant my application access permissions
2b) receive user token from facebook and store it in local database

Basically, the difficulty for me is to query facebook for current user id without passing a user token to facebook. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to query facebook for current user id without passing a user token to facebook

No. This isn't possible, facebook will never give you user_id without their knowledge. They have to authorize your application first.

Comment: I see for example www.zoho.com don't ask to grant permissions more than once, how could they achieve this?

Comment: You have to approve your application only once per user account. So @lekso you approve it once and then user just clicks "login" and he's logged in without asking